# How to pass data from inappwebview to flutter on button click?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I want to pass some data to flutter from the inappwebview. I tied using the below code, But it's not working. I need to send some data as a json to my dart function for the api call.

```
child: InAppWebView(
                        initialFile:
                            "assets/blockly_webview/pages/index.html",
                        initialOptions: options,
                        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                          controller.addJavaScriptHandler(
                              handlerName: 'handlerFoo',
                              callback: (args) {
                                // return data to the JavaScript side!
                                return {
                                  'env_type': DynamicUI.envType,
                                  'parent_blocks':
                                      currentLevelStatus.parentBlock,
                                  'child_blocks':
                                      currentLevelStatus.childBlock,
                                  'userAccessToken': userAccessToken,
                                  'device_list': userDeviceController
                                      .deviceList[0].deviceId
                                };
                              });
                          controller.addJavaScriptHandler(
                              handlerName: "mySum",
                              callback: (args) {
                                // Here you receive all the arguments from the JavaScript side
                                // that is a List<dynamic>
                                print("From the JavaScript side:");
                                print(args);
                                return args
                                    .reduce((curr, next) => curr + next);
                              });
                        },
                      ),
```

Js code :

```
 function send_Data(){
console.log("call Function is called");
window.addEventListener("flutterInAppWebViewPlatformReady", function(event) {
    window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler('handlerFoo')
      .then(function(result) {
        // print to the console the data coming
        // from the Flutter side.
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        
        window.flutter_inappwebview
          .callHandler('handlerFooWithArgs', 1, true, ['bar', 5], {foo: 'baz'}, result);
    });
})
```

}

Answer (score 0):

- You have not added javascript handler in dart code for 'handlerFooWithArgs' call function, you are listening to handler named 'mySum'. Just check if this is the issue.